# SFDX-Git-Delta plugin not finding differences between branches in github action

Tags: sfdx-plugin, github, cicd

I have my yml file for my github action set up like this:

```
name: Test Deploy Delta

on: 
  push:
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
build:
runs-on: windows-latest

steps:
- name: Check out repository code
  uses: actions/checkout@v2
    
# Install Salesforce CLI
- name: Install Salesforce CLI 
  run: |
    npm install sfdx-cli
    node_modules/sfdx-cli/bin/run version

- name: Install sfdxGit delta
  run: |
    echo y | node_modules/sfdx-cli/bin/run plugins:install sfdx-git-delta
    node_modules/sfdx-cli/bin/run plugins

- name: Generate SFDX Delta Package
  run: |
    mkdir changes
    node_modules/sfdx-cli/bin/run sgd:source:delta --to test-branch --from master --output changes
    echo "--- package.xml generated with added and modified metadata ---"
    cat changes/package/package.xml
    echo ""
    echo "--- destructiveChanges.xml generated with deleted metadata ---"
    cat changes/destructiveChanges/destructiveChanges.xml
    echo
```

Where I am using the [sfdx-git-delta](https://github.com/scolladon/sfdx-git-delta) plugin to optimize a deploy. When I run `sfdx sgd:source:delta --to test-branch --from master --output changes` in my VS Code terminal, I get a package.xml in my changes folder that has the differences between the branches, which there are. When this github action runs, though. it always produces an empty package.xml and I have no idea why.

I do not understand why this is failing in the github action. The `node_modules/sfdx-cli/bin/run version` command returns `sfdx-cli/7.102.0 linux-x64 node-v14.17.0` and all sfdx-git-delta requires is node 14.6.0, so that shouldn't be a problem. It should have everything it needs.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to execute this command before you will execute sgd

```
git fetch origin "+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*"
```